# Problem setting up Elastic Search single-node cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing, elasticsearch-7

I am trying to set up ElasticSearch 7.3.1 in single-node cluster.

I tried adding:

`discovery.type: single-node`

But then I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot start with [discovery.type] set to [single-node] when local node {node-1}{O846-1yHRLiOGzLUx
>   4RycQ}{KKT2Ljj3QUWiFR4K1ICrDg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{dim}{ml.machine_memory=17179262976, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20} does not have quorum in voting configura
>   tion VotingConfiguration

If i remove the line `discovery.type: single-node` then I get the following error:

> master not discovered or elected yet, an election requires two nodes with ids [O846-1yHRLiOGzLUx
>   4RycQ, j1tBqJEtSXO78j6Ym8OceA], have discovered [{node-1}{O846-1yHRLiOGzLUx4RycQ}{KE4tPTGtS7ukT7k-6iLxaw}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{dim}{ml.machine_memory=17179262976, xpack.in
>   stalled=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}] which is not a quorum; discovery will continue using [127.0.0.1:9301, 127.0.0.1:9302, 127.0.0.1:9303, 127.0.0.1:9304, 127.0.0.1:9305, [::1]:9
>   301, [::1]:9302, [::1]:9303, [::1]:9304, [::1]:9305] from hosts providers and [{node-1}{O846-1yHRLiOGzLUx4RycQ}{KE4tPTGtS7ukT7k-6iLxaw}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{dim}{ml.machin
>   e_memory=17179262976, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20}] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0

Comment: I didnt set that config for only one node

Comment: I didnt understand your comment

Comment: @Roy I  am facing similar problem.Did you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 7):

> `an election requires two nodes with ids [O846-1yHRLiOGzLUx 4RycQ, j1tBqJEtSXO78j6Ym8OceA],`

This node previously belonged to a 2-node cluster, and you have removed one (i.e. half of them) without following the [proper procedure](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/add-elasticsearch-nodes.html) which is required to do this without losing data.

There are two ways forward:

1. Form the 2-node cluster again and then [remove one node properly](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/add-elasticsearch-nodes.html).
2. Wipe the data path and start again afresh.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer!
My problem is that I didn't deleted any node!
I have just unzip the zip file and try to run the elasticsearch.bat file..

Comment: I am certain that somehow you had two nodes running at the same time at some point in the past. Perhaps you ran it twice? It doesn't really matter, the fix is still the same: wipe the data path and try again.